# How to install python package in snowflake which is not a part of anaconda

Tags: python, azure-devops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am working on decrypting files (.pgp) from a location in my ADLS, To do that I need to use private key that's in my azure keyvault, I am using Snowflake Python worksheet, as of now I want python library like pgpy,os,base64,azure_keyvault,azure_identity.
Is there any way I can import these libraries that's not a part of anaconda package.
I've staged these library as .whl files but i need help in importing these libraries in my worksheet.

I've staged the .whl files of the required python package in my snowflake.
but struggling how to import them to my worksheet.
Is there any way to use them,
I've also tried sql stored procedure but its not working also
Can anyone help me in the complete step by stepo manner how to do that

Also, I've seen that if I staged .Py file we can simply use Import command. So, if I was able to convert the entire azure identity python package to one .py file I'll be able to import it import it directly.

[Stagged files in snowflake here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4UB5.png)
[python packages here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srFI8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this

1. Add the package to Stage Packages
   [image: Snowflake Python worksheets stage packages]
2. Get the Snowflake import directory
3. Append the wheel file to the system path
4. Import from the library

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

# Add wheel to system path to enable stage package import
import sys
import_dir = sys._xoptions.get("snowflake_import_directory")
sys.path.append(import_dir + "python_ulid-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl")
from ulid import ULID

def ulid(session: snowpark.Session):
  a_ulid = ULID()
  return str(a_ulid)
```